# Write Text file with tab-delimited in Asp.Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, text-files, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

Hi do you have any guides, work aid or step by step how to export to text with tab delimited. Im using Asp.Net Core 2.2 MVC EF. I want to export a list from my table.. I want to have a button where the user click in this DownloadFile Action will trigger.

```
public IActionResult DownloadFile()
        {
            var payments = new List<BdoPE>
            {
                new BdoPE
                {
                    DocDateInDoc = "01/01/2019",
                    DocType = "DZ",
                    CompanyCode = "3000",
                    PosDateInDoc = "01/01/2019",
                    FiscalPeriod = "01",
                    CurrentKey = "PHP",
                    RefDocNum = "Over-The-Counter",
                    DocHeadT = "BDO",
                    PosKeyInNextLine = "40",
                    AccMatNextLine = "11231131",
                    AmountDocCur = "0000000010050",
                    ValDate = "01/01/2019",
                    AssignNum = "EEA",
                    ItemText = "1000136212  ",
                    PosKeyInNextLine2 = "15",
                    AccMatNextLine2 = "0115027FF",
                    AmountDocCur2 = "0000000010050",
                    BaseDateDueCal = "01/01/2019",
                    ItemText2 = "1000136212"
                },
            };

            // I want this part to let the user select where they want to save the text file.
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.txt")) // not static location like this one.

            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
            {
                csv.WriteHeader<BdoPE>();
                csv.WriteRecord(payments);
            }

            // where should i put the delimiter part?

            return; 
        }
```

Comment: Where does the `CsvWriter` class come from?

Comment: I'm using CsvHelper from this page https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear. You need the `CsvWriter(TextWriter, Configuration)` constructor and the [Configuration](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration/Configuration/) object has a `Delimiter` property that you can set.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just newbie in .Net core, I'm still having a hard time.

Comment: Well, your question was good enough to get the next hint, so you're all good :)

Comment: Hi can you show me some code so I have an idea? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the code below to set the Delimiter using CsvHelper.

```
 var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
 {
      Delimiter = "\t"
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup the CsvWriter with a [Configuration](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration/Configuration/).

Thus, your code needs only a slight change:

```
[...]
var configuration = new CsvHelper.Configuration.Configuration();
configuration.Delimiter = '\t';

using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, configuration))
{
    csv.WriteHeader<BdoPE>();
    csv.WriteRecord(payments);
}
[...]
```